# Mocking out/replacing return from S3 library SelectObjectContentEventStream.getRecordsInputStream()

Tags: java, unit-testing, amazon-s3, mockito

I’m trying to create some unit tests around a call to AWS S3 Select and having trouble mocking out the SelectRecordsInputStream returned from getRecordsInputStream(). I’m unable to instantiate my own SelectRecordsInputStream as the class is package private and I’m unable to return an instance of InputStream from Mockito’s .thenReturn() as its expecting an instance of SelectRecordsInputStream (this confuses me as SelectRecordsInputStream extends InputStream and you’re able to specify this Type as the return in the try with resources)

Is there anything I can do (without bringing in another testing framework) to return my own instance of InputStream or SelectRecordsInputStream? It also cannot be a mock instance as the testing revolves around processing the InputStream.

Production Code:

```
List<StockAvailability> stockList = Collections.emptyList();

SelectObjectContentResult result = s3Client.selectObjectContent(query);

try (InputStream resultInputStream = result.getPayload().getRecordsInputStream()) {
   stockList = transformResponse(resultInputStream);
}
catch (IOException e) {
   LOG.error("Unable to parse stock availability response: {}", e.getMessage());
}
```

Unit test:

```
   @Test
     void test1()  {
     final Query query = new Query.QueryBuilder().query(SELECT_QUERY)
                                               .bucket(BUCKET)
                                               .objectKey(KEY)
                                               .build();

     when(s3Client.selectObjectContent (query)).thenReturn(selectObjectContentResult);

     byte[] string = "Any String you want".getBytes();

     InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(string);
when(selectObjectContentResult.getPayload()).thenReturn(selectObjectContentEventStream);
   
     //Does not compile and cannot cast to SelectRecordsInputStream       
     when(selectObjectContentEventStream.getRecordsInputStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);

     final List<StockAvailability> result = stockService.queryStockData(query);
  }
```

Comment: I don't see where you're mocking getPayload()

Comment: @tgdavies whoops, updated example test.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for but here's how I implemented unit testing for S3 Select:

**Production Code**:

```java
List<StockAvailability> stockList = Collections.emptyList();

SelectObjectContentResult result = s3Client.selectObjectContent(query);

try (SelectRecordsInputStream resultInputStream = result.getPayload().getRecordsInputStream()) {
   stockList = transformResponse(resultInputStream.getDelegateStream());
}
catch (IOException e) {
   LOG.error("Unable to parse stock availability response: {}", e.getMessage());
}
```

*Note the call to `getDelegateStream()`*

**Unit test**:

```java
   @Test
   void test1()  {
        SelectObjectContentResult mockSelectObjectContentResult = mock(SelectObjectContentResult.class);
        SelectObjectContentEventStream mockSelectObjectContentEventStream = mock(SelectObjectContentEventStream.class);
        SelectRecordsInputStream mockSelectRecordsInputStream = mock(SelectRecordsInputStream.class);

        when(mockS3.selectObjectContent(any())).thenReturn(mockSelectObjectContentResult);
        when(mockSelectObjectContentResult.getPayload()).thenReturn(mockSelectObjectContentEventStream);
        when(mockSelectObjectContentEventStream.getRecordsInputStream()).thenReturn(mockSelectRecordsInputStream);

        final InputStream output = IOUtils.toInputStream("some string", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        when(mockSelectRecordsInputStream.getDelegateStream()).thenReturn(output);
  }
```